# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz'] when executing python3?

Tags: python3, numpy

I have installed numpy and pytz packages through

```
pip3 install <package name>
```

But there shows the following import errors when executing the following df_demo.py code, I do not know why and how to fix this issue ? because I have served the internet can not find a clear way to solve !!

```
paultsai@paultsai-virtual-machine:~/python_data_analysis/3358OS_04_Code/code4$ python3 df_demo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "df_demo.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy', 'pytz']
```

df_demo.py

```
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
df = read_csv("WHO_first9cols.csv")
print ("Dataframe",df)
print ("Shape", df.shape)
print ("Length", len(df))
print ("Column Headers", df.columns)
print ("Data types", df.dtypes)
print ("Index", df.index)
print ("Values", df.values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your installation through pip was successful or has been somewhere out of scope (for example for another user in you used `--user` flag or in a virtual env)

We could discuss and solve that but the easiest way to get you going is to install `pandas` through Ubuntu repositories and apt would take care of installing dependencies. You can do this from software center or by:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

Comment: I retried and reinstalled those python3 version tools by entering the following command:                                                                               `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`                                                    `sudo apt-get install python3-scipy` and                                                        `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`. It seems there is no longer with the above problems when executing the following cmd:                                                       `python3 xxx.py`